# Unable to install Hubstaff client for Linux

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu

Cannot install Hubstaff official client,
when I execute

```
Hubstaff-1.5.17-52c95d23.sh
```

I see the following error:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Mojo Setup..............
Collecting info for this system...
Operating system: linux
CPU Arch: x86_64
trying mojosetup in bin/linux/x86_64
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Error: Couldn't run mojosetup
```

Tried to follow different mojosetup instruction but still no luck,
sent an email to their support team but still no answer.
Could you please assist

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ? How long ago did you send the email?

Comment: I sent email yesterday, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: You expected an answer already and on a weekend not very practical.

Comment: you are right, nothing left to say let's just wait...

Comment: Have you tried to redownload the setup file? What is the output of `md5sum Hubstaff-1.5.17-52c95d23.sh` ? I see 41ba020c6d808eec6355e283387b0d67 and it installs normally on my fresh 20.04 LTS VM.

Comment: yeah, two times,
and its the same md5sum for me  41ba020c6d808eec6355e283387b0d67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answer will save your time :)

```
mkdir installer
./Hubstaff-1.5.17-52c95d23.sh  --tar xvf -C installer 
ldd ./installer/bin/linux/x86_64/guis/libmojosetupgui_gtkplus2.so
ldd ./installer/bin/linux/x86_64/guis/libmojosetupgui_ncurses.so
MOJOSETUP_UI=ncurses ./Hubstaff-1.5.17-52c95d23.sh
```